# Moving a file by linux .sh scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have setup a script to perform automatic backups of my `/var/www` directory to `/root/Dropbox`.

When the script is executed by Cron the backup file is moved to `/root/` instead of `/root/Dropbox/`. I have set the permissions of the Dropbox directory to `722`, so there should be no problem writing to it.

The script is the following:

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")

#backup site

if tar -zcvf site-www-var-$NOW.tar.gz '/var/www'; then
    echo "Backup of data created." 1>&2

    if mv /home/site-www-var-* /root/Dropbox/; then
        echo "Data Moved." 1>&2
    else
        echo "Data move failed." 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
else
    echo "Data backup failed." 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The output is the following:

```
Backup of data created.
Data Moved.
```

Comment: the command is probably not moving .. it's rather the tar that is creating the file under /root/Dropbox

Comment: Apologies guys i should have used `root` in the question not `home`

Comment: You are probably (what is your working directory?) running the `tar` command in `/root`, but your `mv` command is expecting the data to be inside `/home`.

Comment: Why aren't you creating the file where you want it in the first place? `tar` can handle files with paths just as well as `mv`.

Comment: @tripleee does that mean i can have `tar -zcvf /root/Dropbox/site-www-var-$NOW.tar.gz '/var/www'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @La Kantara said, this line

```
if tar -zcvf site-www-var-$NOW.tar.gz '/var/www'; then
```

is likely creating the tarball file in the `Current working directory` of the user which executed the command.

Therefore I would simply change the `tar` command to use the full file path for your tarball.

```
if tar -zcvf /root/Dropbox/site-www-var-$NOW.tar.gz '/var/www'; then
              ^^^  ^^^^^^^
```

In which case your `mv` command would become redundant also

Answer (score -1):

if tar -zcvf site-www-var-$NOW.tar.gz '/var/www'; then

if tar -zcvf /root/Dropbox/site-www-var-$NOW.tar.gz '/var/www'; then